# https get request with python proxy doesn't work

Tags: python, https, proxy, request

I've looked at and tried several stack solutions regarding the https requests using a proxy with python, and I've seen the discussions on GitHub.

My impression was that the requests library in python 3 now has support for https requests using a proxy and so I don't understand why mine doesn't work:

```
import requests

proxydict = {
'http':'http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:5555/',
'https':'https://xx.xx.xxx.xx:5555/'
}

requests.get('https://www.google.co.uk',proxies = proxydict).
```

When I run this code I get:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.python.org', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: 
Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

I was used a postman proxy to do this.
My http requests with a proxy work fine. Can someone help?

Edit:
I wanted to do this with a corporate proxy so I can't simply use a different proxy. Also, the https addresses work fine in the browser, it's simply when I do a python request with the proxy as described in the documentation that this error occurs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi because your proxy is not working with ssl 
or your proxy is used try other 
from here
https://www.sslproxies.org/
scroll down and you see https proxies

Comment: When i access https websites through the browser while using the proxy it works fine. It's only when i do a python request. I'm trying to fix this so that I can use the solution for a corporate proxy where error is the same, and where I don't have a choice of proxy to use. For the corporate proxy as well, I can access the https websites through the browser, it's only for the python request that this doesn't work.

Comment: try to use https proxy and do this

Comment: import requests

proxydict = {
'https':'https://xx.xx.xxx.xx:5555/'
}

requests.get('https://www.google.co.uk',proxies = proxydict).

Comment: remove http and use https

Comment: Yeah that has no effect on the error message. Incidentally, the code was already trying to use the https.